# How to get the value of an attribute of the root element in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <IMPORT mode="FULL">
    ....
 </IMPORT>
```

I'm trying to convert it with the following [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Transformations) stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="import">
      <xsl:attribute name="mode">
        <xsl:value-of select="@mode"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
           ....
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

My problem is that the following line doesn't seem to work:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@mode"/>
```

As I only get

```
<import mode="">
```

instead of the expected:

```
<import mode="FULL">
```

Any clues ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use `<xsl:value-of select="IMPORT/@mode"/>`

Answer (score 8):

You're not actually on the `IMPORT` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="IMPORT"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="IMPORT">
    <xsl:element name="import">
      <xsl:attribute name="mode">
        <xsl:value-of select="@mode"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
       ....      
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="IMPORT">
    <xsl:element name="import">
        <xsl:attribute name="mode">
            <xsl:value-of select="@mode"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```